# When logging in navbar does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I have run into a problem, that i have no errors on, but it does not do what was intended, I am using react.js and react-token-auth. When I login My navbar does not update to the LoggedInLinks() so here is my question Is it a typo again, or did i do something the wrong way.

Here is my auth.js:

```
import { createAuthProvider } from "react-token-auth";

export const { useAuth, authFetch, login, logout } = createAuthProvider({
  accessTokenKey: "access_token",
  onUpdateToken: (token) =>
    fetch("/Auth/refresh", {
      method: "POST",
      body: token.refresh_token,
    }).then((res) => res.json()),
});
```

and here is my nav bar code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./NavBar.scss";
import {
  Nav,
  NavLink,
  Bars,
  NavMenu,
  NavBtn,
  NavBtnLink,
} from "./NavbarElements";
import { useAuth, logout } from "../Auth/auth";

const LoggedInLinks = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavMenu>
      <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/contact-us">Contact</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="Services">Services</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/forum">Forum</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/dev-blog">Dev Blog</NavLink>
      </NavMenu>
      <NavBtn>
        <NavBtnLink to="/" onclick={logout()}>Log Out</NavBtnLink>
      </NavBtn>
    </>
  );
};

const LoggedOutLinks = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavMenu>
        <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/contact-us">Contact</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="Services">Services</NavLink>
      </NavMenu>
      <NavBtn>
        <NavBtnLink to="/login">Login</NavBtnLink>
      </NavBtn>
    </>
  );
};

const Navbar = () => {
  const [loggedIn] = useAuth();
console.log(loggedIn);
  return (
    <Nav>
      <div className="brand">
        <img className="logo" src="2-2.png" alt="2-2.png" />
        SinLess Games
      </div>
      <Bars />

      {loggedIn ? <LoggedInLinks /> : <LoggedOutLinks />}

    </Nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

and last but not least as a just in case, the code for my login:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./Login.scss";
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { login } from '../../components/Auth/auth';


const Login = () => {

  const {register, handleSubmit, reset, formState:{errors}} = useForm();

  const loginUser = (data) => {
    console.log(data);

    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };

    fetch("/Auth/login", requestOptions)
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>{
      console.log(data.access_token)
      login(data.access_token)

      navigate('/')
    });

    reset();
  }

  let navigate = useNavigate(); 
  const routeChange = () =>{ 
    let path = `/signup`; 
    navigate(path);
  }

  return (
    <div className="Screen">
      <div className="Break" />
      <div className="Row1 title">
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="Row">
        <div className="Column image">
          <img src="./2-2.png" alt="2-1.png" />
        </div>
        <div className="Column text">
          <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId="SignUp Form">
              <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label>
                  UserName
                </Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="text" 
                placeholder="Enter your UserName"
                {...register("username", {
                  required: true,
                  minLength: 5,
                  maxLength: 50,
                })}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              {errors.Username && (
                <span className="error">
                  Username is required
                  <br />
                </span>
              )}
              {errors.Username?.type === "minLength" && (
                <span className="error">
                  Username must be at least 5 characters
                  <br />
                </span>
              )}
              {errors.Username?.type === "maxLength" && (
                <span className="error">
                  Username must be at most 50 characters
                  <br />
                </span>
              )}
              <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label> 
                  Password
                </Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="password" 
                placeholder="Enter your Password"
                {...register("password", {
                  required: true,
                  minLength: 8,
                  maxLength: 50,
                })}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              {errors.Password && (
                <span className="error">
                  Password is required
                  <br />
                </span>
              )}
              {errors.Password?.type === "minLength" && (
                <span className="error">
                  Password must be at least 8 characters
                  <br />
                </span>
              )}
              {errors.Password?.type === "maxLength" && (
                <span className="error">
                  Password must be at most 50 characters
                  <br />
                </span>
              )}
              <Form.Group>
                <button className="Submit" onClick={handleSubmit(loginUser)}>
                  Login
                </button>
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group>
                <button className="Submit" onClick={routeChange}>
                  Register
                </button>
              </Form.Group>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
         
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

NOTE: I am able to see that i am returning the proper information from my backend API, and that i am not getting an error there. in the browser console, i do get my access_token for the user. Which makes me wonder what it is that i may have messed up with.

Thankyou for your time and input.

UPDATE:
I added console.log(loggedIn) to my navbar.js, right after i state the const loggedIn and when i look at the log it output:

```
true index.js:49 
true react_devtools_backend.js:4082:31 
false index.js:49 
false react_devtools_backend.js:4082:31
```

Comment: I find that using `console.log` at every step that I expect an output really helps in debugging. Once you find that one spot that isn't logging as expected, you've found your source of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was in the navbar, you are calling the function logout, instead of passing a callback (so that it gets called on click).

```
    <NavBtn>
        <NavBtnLink to="/" onclick={logout()}>Log Out</NavBtnLink>
    </NavBtn>
```

Which should have been:

```
    <NavBtn>
        <NavBtnLink to="/" onClick={logout}>Log Out</NavBtnLink>
    </NavBtn>
```

so once again typo and syntax